# Gparted-If it Were to Crash-copying partition

Tags: partitioning, crash, gparted, partition-copy

I was wondering, if you use gparted to copy a entire partition from one hard drive to another, if the system were to crash, obviously it would for lack of better term, mess up the drive you're copying to, but would it, again for lack of better term, mess up the drive being copied from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hard drive being copied from would be fine.  Gparted is just reading the data, which is non destructive.

Its no different than if you were copying a a piece of paper to another with a pen.  If your brain crashed (thats a different issue) nothing would happen to the paper being read from.  However, you might scribble all over the paper being written on.

Sorry, not the best analogy in the world, but it works...

Comment: That's what I thought, but after what's happened in the past months, I find it's always best to consult others to make sure.